# Decomposition of polynomial of n-degree into irreducible polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm getting ready for the exam in algebra. And I have problem that I can't solve [again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276362/decomposition-of-polynomial-into-irreducible-polynomials).

I'm understand what I need to do if I have a polynomial with a given degree. But I very confused by arbitrary degree in this problem.

> Given polynomial
>   $$x^{2n}-2x^n+2$$
>   The task is find expansion of the polynomial as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{2n}-2x^n+2=(x^n-1)^2+1=(x^n-1+i)(x^n-1-i)=(x^n-2^{0.5}e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}})(x^n-2^{0.5}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})$$

Now note that:
$$x^n-2^{0.5}e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}}=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-2^{\frac{1}{2n}}e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}+\frac{-2\pi ik}{n}})$$
$$x^n-2^{0.5}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-2^{\frac{1}{2n}}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}+\frac{2\pi ik}{n}})$$

Hence:
$$x^{2n}-2x^n+2=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-2^{\frac{1}{2n}}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}+\frac{2\pi ik}{n}})(x-2^{\frac{1}{2n}}e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}+\frac{-2\pi ik}{n}})$$
$$x^{2n}-2x^n+2=\prod_{k=1}^n(x^2-(2^{\frac{1}{2n}}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}+\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}+2^{\frac{1}{2n}}e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}+\frac{-2\pi ik}{n}})x+2^{\frac{1}{n}})$$
$$x^{2n}-2x^n+2=\prod_{k=1}^n(x^2-2(2^{\frac{1}{2n}}\cos({\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2\pi k}{n}}))x+2^{\frac{1}{n}})$$

Comment: It should be $\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(x^2-2\left( 2^{ \frac{1}{2n} } \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{2\pi k}{n} \right)\right)x+2^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)}$, right?

Comment: @Pambos Yes thank you